# session in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, security, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I have created a session in asp.net C# page, i'm storing user uniqueid in session like this,

```
Session["userid"] = clsUser.UniqueId;
```

and checking this unique id on each page and redirecting if session is null. But if i copy the users current URL in other tab of IE, it is not redirecting to login page. Instead it is maintaining session across the browser subtabs.

How can i redirect to login page if user try to copy the url in another sub tab?

Comment: Don't do that.  It's very annoying.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It's perfectly acceptable for users to navigate a website in multiple tabs, and it's behavior users expect.  What are you trying to solve/avoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple tabs are in the same session - that's normal behavior. Perhaps you could add a second tracking HiddenField to the page or use ViewState to ensure that the postback is from the same page it came from?

I don't think that there's any real way to prevent this.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it, because each browser's tab share same cookie and asp.net session base on browser cookie

Answer (score 0):

The origina tab has the right Referer. The copied tab has no Referer. Use `Request.UrlReferrer`. Keep in mind, this isn't perfectly secure because a sophisticated user could manipulate the Referer.

Comment: 1) If you open a link in a new tab it has the correct referrer. And I think refreshing keeps the referrer too. 2) Some people have software installed that blocks/replaces their referrer. Those would be unable to use the website.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Request.UrlReferrer  on page load  and it will give you previous page url.

```
if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)

{

//Load page  data as normal you are doing.  

}

else

{

// redirect to login page because user have copied and pasted the URL in new tab 

//  and it do not have it previous page url in **Request.UrlReferrer** property.

}
```